# xmlbeans NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, apache-poi, xmlbeans

I have a Maven project with the following structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>myId</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifactID</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

According to that pom.xml file I have added the POI library and the XMLBeans library as well, but when I try to read the first Excel file I get the NoClassDefFoundError.

I'm using IntelliJ IDE I don't know if that has something to do with this issue or no but yous to give some more detail

Edit: add the class that cause the error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject
```

Comment: Please specify which class you get `NoClassDefFoundError` on

Comment: See http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10204 - you can't mix POI jars between versions!

Comment: `org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject` is in there. So from `Maven` point of you, the config should work. Perhaps some sort of caching problem with IntelliJ, that sort of thing?